# how can find width of a drew string in a bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms

how can i calculate width and height of a string when i draw that in a bitmap???

```
String s="how are you?";
Sraphic boxgraphic;
Bitmap box;
boxgrpahic=Graphic.fromimage(box);
boxgraphic.DrawString(s, new Font("Arial", 10pt), new SolidBrush(Color.black), new Point(0,0));
```

i have a table from conversions of pt to pixel but that not a Formula......

in the an other question,answered to this question but that's do't work currectly..

Points = Pixels * 72 / 96

how can find width of drew string by pixel(Formula)?

Comment: This code does not look valid - `bitmap` and `graphic` are not built in types. Do you mean `Bitmap` and `Graphics`? C# is case sensitive, you know...

Comment: TrueType hinting defeats tables.  Use Graphics.MeasureString().

Comment: yes... i dont pay attention to that....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `graphic.MeasureString(s, new Font("Arial", 10pt))`.
You can also add a `StringFormat.GenericTypographic` parameter to be more accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Use one of the [`MeasureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2h597fsh.aspx) overloads in order to get the string dimensions before drawing it.

```
boxgrpahic=graphic.fromimage(box);
var size = boxgraphic.MeasureString(s, new Font("Arial", 10pt));

var widthPixels = size.Width;

boxgraphic.DrawString(s, new Font("Arial", 10pt), new SolidBrush(Color.black), new point(0,0));
```